# Why .map, .length is not working on array, when it's printing an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

It's printing an array in console but when I use `.map` or `.length`, it prints `undefined` or gives error that `.map is not a function`.

The code is inside the render method:

```
let { faqs } = this.props;
   console.log(faqs); // prints array 
   console.log(this.props.faqs.length) // prints undefined
   let questionList = faqs.length > 0 ? faqs.map((faq) => {
       return <div key={faq._id}>
          <p className='mb-0'>Question: {faq.question}</p>
          <p className='mb-0'>Answer: {faq.answer}</p>
       </div>
   }) : <div> no questions found.</div>
```

This is the console output:

```
{faqs: Array(0)}
undefined
{faqs: Array(5)}
faqs: Array(5)
0: {_id: "5cb44201cdd6fe2749c7ced5", question: "question.1", answer: "this.is.an.answer", __v: 0}
1: {_id: "5cb44255cdd6fe2749c7ced6", question: "sadsfghjkl;", answer: "dsfghjkl;'↵", __v: 0}
2: {_id: "5cb451dbcdd6fe2749c7ced7", question: "dscsfghjk", answer: "sdfghjkl", __v: 0}
3: {_id: "5cb4553ccdd6fe2749c7ced8", question: "weeweqw", answer: "dsadasdsad", __v: 0}
4: {_id: "5cb457b2cdd6fe2749c7ced9", question: "q.5.", answer: "answer.undefined", __v: 0}
undefined
```

Comment: Instead of logging out this.props.faqs.length what does logging out faqs.length show?

Comment: don't you have something like `{ faqs: { faqs: [] } }`? :)

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment, could you update your question with how the props are transferred to your component? Do you have an overview of the actions / reducers and some small sample data of any of the http calls you are making? I really do believe you either have wrong connects, or update the state incorrectly in your reducers

Comment: thanks @Icepickle, yes i have one more nested `faqs` like `faqs.faqs`

Answer (score 3):

According to your logs, it looks like `faqs` is an object containing an array named `faqs`.
Maybe this is a mistake and you want to pass an array directly instead of an object containing an array.

```
<MyComp faqs={[...]} />
```

If so, `const { faqs } = this.props` would give you the array and your code would work.

---

However, if you pass the data as `<MyComp faqs={{ faqs: [...] }} />`, then you can access the inner array via a desctructuring assignment like this:

```
const { faqs: { faqs } } = this.props;
```

This will fix the errors you are having with `.length` returning `undefined` and `.map is not a function`.

Then you would continue like this, first checking if `faqs` is truthy before calling `.length` or `.map`:

```
const questionList = faqs && faqs.length ? faqs.map(faq => { ...
```

---

Note that you can also assign default values in the destructuring assignment so the array is always properly defined and truthy, which avoids polluting the code with `&&` checks everywhere:

```
const { faqs: { faqs = [] } = {} } = this.props;
```

Then you can directly access `.length` and `.map`:

```
const questionList = faqs.length ? faqs.map(faq => {
  return <div key={faq._id}>
    <p className='mb-0'>Question: {faq.question}</p>
    <p className='mb-0'>Answer: {faq.answer}</p>
  </div>
}) : <div> no questions found.</div>
```

Comment: why would you initialize array and object in props destructuralization?

Comment: Wouldn't you consider that you are fighting the symptom, but not the cause? OP should probably investigate why he has the object that he has, while expecting a different one

Comment: @Lukáš Gibo Vaic, to handle the case when faqs is not defined, either on props, or the array property

Comment: thats why he has the faqs.length condition, dont think this is good practice, now you dont know if you recieved empty object, or you made it

Comment: @Lukáš Gibo Vaic, I don't see your point, if the array is empty, either because no object was passed or an object with an empty array was passed, there won't be any questions to print, so the logic still works

Comment: its not about if it works, `if (true) return "a"` is valid code, but not really good one, his code would work even without the inicialization, Iam talking about the fact you are doing it for no reason

Comment: @Lukáš Gibo Vaic, First, his code is not working, hence his question and the `undefined` problems (`faqs` is an object, using `map` on it will crash). Second, it's always good to code robust functions that behave well when given bad input. It's called defensive programming. One way to do it is to give default values like I did.

Comment: yes his problem is that he calls map on object, as mentioned in answer posted 10min before yours, but he doesnt have problem with undefined as you might see in the console.log :-)

Comment: @Lukáš Gibo Vaic, I suggest you re-read the question `I use .map or .length, it prints undefined or gives error that .map is not a function`. Also no answer was posted 10 minutes before mine as I answered 7 minutes after the question was posted

Comment: I think he means he gets undefined on length, dont know what is your problem, gave you an oppinion, cant get over it, well sorry then, just tried to help someone and dont think your initialization helps that much as he per bad input you can have `{faqs: {faqs: {}}}` and it will crash the same way, thats why we have types and catch scopes in react, have a nice day :)

Comment: @Lukáš Gibo Vaic, well I don't see any problem, I simply gave you my opinion too. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

by the console logs, it seems like prop faqs is an object with key faqs which is the array, so in your code do `faqs.faqs.length or map`

Comment: The property is named `faqs`, not `fags`, also this code will fail if `faqs` is not passed as a prop, or if it does not contain an array named `faqs`

Comment: this really only helps identify the outcome, not what might have caused it, so it's not really useful as an answer...

Comment: @Icepickle this helps him to run his code, yes he might have an error in his model, but we might aswel be solving extra renders if you take this approach (one problem at the time my friend :-))

Comment: well, you might be right, just jo_va's answer really tries to get down in the root cause, which looks to be a more in depth answer. What happens in your case when `faqs` only gets filled async (so a render does occur before `faqs` might be filled) :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case initially there is no values for faqs. `.map` & `.length` only works on array. Thats why it returns undefined

so you have to do an if condition on `faqs`

```
if(faqs)
  console.log(faqs.length)
```

And

```
faqs && faqs.map(item => return {
   .......
} )
```

Comment: if he would run length on undefined it would be syntax error, undefined is returned because he is trying to use length on object, which would translate to, get "undefined" key from object and that returns undefined

Comment: You could always try `Array.isArray( faqs )` instead, but it seems the OP has an array somewhere, he just has the wrong data